# How can I add different set of dictionaries into one

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I merge three different set of dictionary to new one suppose if input is

```
d1 = {'name':'tom', 'age':'14', 'sex':'m'}
d2 = {'color':'w', 'weight':'58','style':'good'}
d3 = {'sports':'cricket','music':'rock','dance':'disco'}
```

Output should be `d = {'name':'tom', 'age':'14', 'sex':'m','color':'w', 'weight':'58','style':'good','sports':'cricket','music':'rock','dance':'disco'}`
 I tried using update method, it is suitable for only two dictionary, if I use 3 set it results in repetation,so how can I merge three dictionary into single one

Comment: @venky__ not merging , i want to add

Comment: how is it different? can you clarify your question?

Comment: Are the keys in the three dictionaries unique?

Comment: yeah @wwii some are unique, maybe this is why I am getting repetition of one set, How can I fix this?

Comment: I see four answers that solve your problem.  Maybe your use of `repetition` is confusing us: a dictionary cannot have *repetition* in its keys.  If the answers given don't solve your problem, you aren't explaining it well enough - you should show your attempt, its result and show/explain how that result is wrong ... [mcve].  Welcome to SO, please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.

Comment: @venky__  these are my actual dictionaries                                                         d1 = {'runs1': '11', 'runs2': '2', 'balls1': '32', 'six2': '0', 'fours2': '0', 'name2': 'Amla', 'name1': 'Elgar*', 'balls2': '12', 'six1': '0', 'fours1': '1'}
d2 = {'overs5': '0.3', 'name5': 'Bumrah*', 'name6': 'Shami', 'maidens6': '1', 'maidens5': '0', 'runs6': '7', 'overs6': '4', 'wickets6': '1', 'runs5': '2', 'wickets5': '0'}

Comment: d3 = {'batting_score_desription': '1st Inns', 'progress2': 'stump', 'bowling_score_wickets': '10', 'teams2': 'RSA vs IND', 'Bowling team': 'IND', 'Batting team': 'RSA', 'bowling_score_runs': '187', 'series2': 'India tour of South Africa, 2017-18', 'batting_score_runs': '194', 'bowling_score_overs': '76.4', 'matchtype2': 'TEST', 'matchid2': '4', 'batting_score_wickets': '10', 'bowling_score_desription': '1st Inns', 'batting_score_overs': '65.5', 'status2': 'RSA need 224 runs', 'matchno2': '3rd Test'} @wwii

Comment: @wwii these are my actual dictionaries I iterate these over a loop

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a recent version of Python (>= 3.5), you can take advantage of [unpacking in mapping literals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

```
d1 = {'name':'tom', 'age':'14', 'sex':'m'}
d2 = {'color':'w', 'weight':'58','style':'good'}
d3 = {'sports':'cricket','music':'rock','dance':'disco'}

new_dict = {**d1, **d2, **d3}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=update#dict.update) will work:

```
d1 = {'name':'tom', 'age':'14', 'sex':'m'}
d2 = {'color':'w', 'weight':'58','style':'good'}
d3 = {'sports':'cricket','music':'rock','dance':'disco'}

d1.update(d2)
d1.update(d3)
print(d1)
```

Comment: this results in a repetition

Comment: What kind of repetition?

Comment: @nihkil, [What repetition?](https://repl.it/repls/JumpyHopefulDodo)

Comment: You wanted `{'name': 'tom', 'age': '14', 'sex': 'm', 'color': 'w', 'weight': '58', 'style': 'good', 'sports': 'cricket', 'music': 'rock', 'dance': 'disco'}` as the result and my example gives exactly that.

Comment: My mistake , I did some mistake in my code

Answer (score 1):

The Pythonic way:

```
{**d1, **d2, **d3}
```

Watch out for duplicate keys in the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem using two lines? If not, I would recommend:

```
d1.update(d2)
d1.update(d3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet an other option is to use [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> d1 = {'name':'tom', 'age':'14', 'sex':'m'}
>>> d2 = {'color':'w', 'weight':'58','style':'good'}
>>> d3 = {'sports':'cricket','music':'rock','dance':'disco'}
>>> result = ChainMap(d1, d2, d3)
>>> result
ChainMap({'age': '14', 'name': 'tom', 'sex': 'm'}, {'color': 'w', 'style': 'good', 'weight': '58'}, {'music': 'rock', 'dance': 'disco', 'sports': 'cricket'})
```

The `ChainMap` will behave *mostly* like the merged `dict` you want. And you can always convert it to a plain `dict` by:

```
>>> dict(result)
{'name': 'tom', 'dance': 'disco', 'color': 'w', 'weight': '58', 'style': 'good', 'age': '14', 'music': 'rock', 'sex': 'm', 'sports': 'cricket'}
```

You could also write a simple wrapper function for simplicity of usage:

```
from collections import ChainMap

def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    return dict(ChainMap(*dicts))
```

---

**Note**: It was introduced in python 3.3